# Basis of Quaternion Algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory

I was reading some notes in which the definition of quaternion algebra is given as :

For $a,b \in k^{*}$ ,we define $k$-algebra
by generators and relations as follows: it has two genrators $i$ and $j$ and is subject to the relations $i^2 = a,  j^2 = b, ij=-ij$.Any k-algebra isomophic to this is called a quaternion algebra.

Now,to prove that $ {{1,i,j,ij}}$ is the basis for the quaternion algebra,it is easy to check that this is the spanning set.But to show the $k$-linear independence,they say that it is enough to check that the $k$-algebra with ${1,i,j,ij}$ as basis is associative.

I am not getting this that how will the associativity of the algebra will imply the linear independence.(it might be simple but I am stuck at this).

Comment: What is the formal definition of a $k$-algebra generated by generators and relations?  I would have expected (I guess wrongly) that associativity was built into that...  And, if it doesn't include associativity, how do you know there is a $k$-algebra with basis $\{1,i,j,ij\}$ ?

Comment: [link](http://math.uga.edu/~pete/noncommutativealgebra.pdf)In these notes,he doesn't give a formal definition as such except what I mentioned above. I also have the same doubt as you. Please have a look at the notes.I tried to check the associativity for the basis elements(I think that will suffice) and it is just fine.So,the way quaternion algebra is defined associativity is inbulit and so is the linear independence (going as per the notes,however the implication of linear independence due to associativity is not clear to me).@Jason

Comment: See the first proof of Lemma 3.2 in [my *Why quaternion algebras have rank $4$*](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/quaternion.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear to me as well, especially because $1, i, j, ij$ need not be linearly independent when the characteristic of $k$ is $2$, so linear independence cannot be a purely algebraic consequence. In the characteristic $2$ case, it depends on the precise definition of the algebra: if all you require is that $i$ and $j$ generate it, then one could simply have $i, j \in k$ and the algebra is equal to $k$. With the definition below however, they are linearly independent:

A formal definition of that algebra would be
$$\frac{k\langle i, j \rangle}{(i^2-a, j^2-b, ij + ji)},$$
a quotient of the free associative algebra on two generators $i, j$. It is then not hard to see that $1, i, j, ij$ form a basis, by looking at the degree of elements of $k \langle x, y \rangle$. The argument also works in characterstic $2$, but the algebra you get is always isomorphic to the commutative algebra
$$\frac{k[ i, j ]}{(i^2, j^2)}$$
which is not a quaternion algebra (it is not central nor simple).

Comment: Pretty sure Pete Clark means that the algebra is defined by those generators and relations, rather than just having those generators satisfy those relations and maybe others.